# Nabla Terms in the Energy Density of the Lagrangian for the Massive Spin 1 Field (Schwartz QFT 1st Ed. Eqn. 8.19)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism

The relevant part starts with a Lagrangian guess of,

$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}+\frac{1}{2}m^2A_{\mu}^2$$

where the EOM's are,

$$(\Box+m^2)A_{\mu}=0$$

The book then proceeds to energy density,

$$\mathcal{E}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_tA_{\mu})}\partial_tA_{\mu}-\mathcal{L}$$

Directly stating the result,

$=-\frac{1}{2}[(\partial_tA_{0})^2+(\vec{\nabla}A_0)^2+m^2A_0^2]+\frac{1}{2}[(\partial_t\vec{A})^2+(\nabla_iA_j)^2+m^2\vec{A}^2]$

I am trying to get the terms right by evaluating the energy density $\mathcal{E}$. But I can't recover terms with $\nabla$'s. When I apply Lorentz Gauge I can get the $\nabla_iA_j$ term but then for $\vec{\nabla}A_0$ term I have something like 
$-\partial_tA_{0}\partial_t\vec{A}$ and I am stuck.

Can anyone point me a way to recover these terms?

Comment: To get that result, you don't need to apply any gauge.

Comment: How can you get any terms mixing $A_0$ and $\vec A$? I don't see any point where such a thing could happen. Both your Lagrangian and the energy density definition always contract $\mu$ with $\mu$ in the indices of $A$...